# Why is the base class method called if the derived class overrides the method?

Tags: c++, inheritance

consider the following program:

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual void foo() const {
        cout << "Base::foo()" << endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    virtual void foo() {
        cout << "Derived::foo()" << endl;
    }
};

void func(Base& obj) {
    obj.foo();
}

void main() {
    Derived d;
    func(d); // Base::foo() is printed 
}
```

If I remove the `const` from the `Base` class `foo` method then `Derived::foo()` is called.
I can't seem to understand this behavior.

1) What is the reason for this behavior?

2) Is this decided at compile time or runtime?

Thanks

Comment: 1) not overriding 2) yes

Comment: If the signature is different, it is not an override!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the derived class, the function signature is this:

```
virtual void foo(); //Derived::foo
```

which doesn't mention `const`.  Its a non-const member function, while the `Base::foo` is a **const** member function. They're two different functions, because `const` is a part of the function signature.

```
virtual void foo() const; //Base::foo
```

Derived class does NOT override this function, instead it adds another function.

So the fix is this:

```
class Derived : public Base {
public:
    virtual void foo() const {
        cout << "Derived::foo()" << endl;
    }
};
```

As `const` is a part of the function signature. So you must mention it when you intend to override base's foo.

---

@davka's asked:

> so why the const version is selected over the non-const? Is there any rule or it just happened to be the first option?

Its because the *static* type of `obj` is `Base`, and function name is resolved based on the static type of object. `Base` doesn't even have *non-const* version. So there is no question of it being selected or rejected. It doesn't exist in `Base` to begin with.

```
void func(Base& obj) {
    obj.foo();  //calls Base::foo
}
```

However, if you change the above code to the following:

```
void func(Derived & obj) {
    obj.foo();  //calls Derived:foo
}
```

Now non-const version will be selected, because `Base::foo` is hidden in `Derived` class.

---

Since `Derived::foo` hides the `Base::foo`, so you cannot call the latter using an instance of `Derived`.

Now, lets unhide `Base::foo` and do some more experiments.

```
class Derived : public Base {
public:
    using Base::foo;         //<----------------this unhides Base::foo
    virtual void foo() {
        cout << "Derived::foo()" << endl;
    }
};
```

Now in Derived, both functions (const as well as non-const version) are available, unhidden. Now few interesting questions.

Since now Derived has both functions unhidden, which function will be called in each function below?

```
void f(Derived& obj) {
    obj.foo(); //Which function? Base::foo or Derived::foo?
}
void g(const Derived & obj) {
    obj.foo(); //Which function? Base::foo or Derived::foo?
}
```

First one will call `Derived::foo` which is non-const version, and second one will call `Base::foo` which is const version. The reason is simple, with const object, **only** *const* functions can be invoked, but with non-const objects, both can be invoked, however non-const version is selected if its available.

See online demo : http://www.ideone.com/955aY

Comment: so why the const version is selected over the non-const? Is there any rule or it just happened to be the first option?

Comment: of course, stupid me :( thanks. Sometimes you are so used to the complexities that you forget the basics :)

Answer (score 3):

You aren't overriding the method, since `Derived::foo` isn't exactly the same.

To override a method, the base and overridden versions must be identical, including `const`-ness.

Comment: Note that it doesn't have to be _exactly_ the same; the return type of the override may be covariant with the return type of the function being overridden.

Comment: @James: also parameter types may be contravariant.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, you can have two functions with the same name and the same parameters, where the only difference that one is `const` and one is not.

The idea is that you sometimes want different behaviors. For example, an access function function might have different return types:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
  virtual Xxx * GetXxx();
  virtual Xxx const * GetXxx() const;
  // ....
}
```

You can override these functions individually.

In your case, as you call `foo` from a non-const object, you called the non-const variant of the function. As you had overridden the const-variant, the one in the base class is the one being called.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is called "overloading."  In overriding, as @SLaks pointed out, the signature needs to be the same.

Comment: It's not really overloading either; it's hiding.

Answer (score 0):

`const` is part of the signature. `void foo() const` is a different function from `void foo()`. You are not overriding at all. That's why.